Snowflake get previous value that was different
I have a table that tracks location by id along with dates a devices was issued and the product/accessory that has been associated to the device. The location can only have 1 device at a time, and the device may get a new accessory every so often. Each time a new accessory is associated, a new record is created.
I am trying to add to each record the previous device information if there was a one.
I have a table like below:



ID_NO
DEVICE_NO
DEVICE_DATE
PRODUCT_NO
PRODUCT_DATE




FD2A
600076
2011-09-20
210785
2012-01-03


FD2A
208049
2017-09-11
066762
2017-09-11


FD2A
208049
2017-09-11
009802
2023-09-12


C600
202650
2009-03-25
127677
2009-03-25


C600
215580
2012-04-04
127677
2010-10-06


C600
215580
2012-04-04
245791
2012-04-10


C600
215580
2012-04-04
366424
2013-09-06


C600
215580
2012-04-04
105547
2014-01-31


C600
215580
2012-04-04
503592
2015-10-01


C600
209855
2015-11-16
484106
2015-10-09


C600
600382
2020-08-24
347302
2016-08-25



Using the following query:
select
id_no
,device_no
,device_date
,product_no
,product_date
,lag(device_no) over (partition by id_no order by device_date, product_date) prev_device_no
,lag(device_date) over (partition by id_no order by device_date, product_date) prev_device_date
from device_data
order by id_no,device_date,product_date

I get the following result:



ID_NO
DEVICE_NO
DEVICE_DATE
PRODUCT_NO
PRODUCT_DATE
PREV_DEVICE_NO
PREV_DEVICE_DATE




FD2A
600076
2011-09-20
210785
2012-01-03




FD2A
208049
2017-09-11
066762
2017-09-11
600076
2011-09-20


FD2A
208049
2017-09-11
009802
2023-09-12
208049
2017-09-11


C600
202650
2009-03-25
127677
2009-03-25




C600
215580
2012-04-04
127677
2010-10-06
202650
2009-03-25


C600
215580
2012-04-04
245791
2012-04-10
215580
2012-04-04


C600
215580
2012-04-04
366424
2013-09-06
215580
2012-04-04


C600
215580
2012-04-04
105547
2014-01-31
215580
2012-04-04


C600
215580
2012-04-04
503592
2015-10-01
215580
2012-04-04


C600
209855
2015-11-16
484106
2015-10-09
215580
2012-04-04


C600
600382
2020-08-24
347302
2016-08-25
209855
2015-11-16



What I really want to do is get the previous device_no and date that was different:
like this:



ID_NO
DEVICE_NO
DEVICE_DATE
PRODUCT_NO
PRODUCT_DATE
PREV_DEVICE_NO
PREV_DEVICE_DATE




FD2A
600076
2011-09-20
210785
2012-01-03




FD2A
208049
2017-09-11
066762
2017-09-11
600076
2011-09-20


FD2A
208049
2017-09-11
009802
2023-09-12
600076
2011-09-20


C600
202650
2009-03-25
127677
2009-03-25




C600
215580
2012-04-04
127677
2010-10-06
202650
2009-03-25


C600
215580
2012-04-04
245791
2012-04-10
202650
2009-03-25


C600
215580
2012-04-04
366424
2013-09-06
202650
2009-03-25


C600
215580
2012-04-04
105547
2014-01-31
202650
2009-03-25


C600
215580
2012-04-04
503592
2015-10-01
202650
2009-03-25


C600
209855
2015-11-16
484106
2015-10-09
215580
2012-04-04


C600
600382
2020-08-24
347302
2016-08-25
209855
2015-11-16



is there another function to get the last different value when partitioning?

Hi - please format your question so that it is readable: code as code, data as tables, etc

fixed. sorry new to this format.

I think I have something that will work for you here.  I only tested it with the first data group, so it might need tweaking.
What I do is, take your table and find all of the records that are different based on device_no.  I am making assumption that the device_no does not change and then change back to a previous value....I think that would break this.
Once I have that in the data_delta CTE, then I can do an asof join to get the previous "change record" for every record that I had in the original table.
Full code looks like this, but the first data CTE is just some of your sample data:
with data as (
    select *
    from (values('FD2A',600076,'2011-09-20'::date,'2012-01-03'::date),      
    ('FD2A',208049,'2017-09-11'::date,'2017-09-11'::date),
    ('FD2A',208049,'2017-09-11'::date,'2023-09-12'::date)
    ) x (id_no,device_no,device_date,product_date)
), data_delta as (
    select * from data
    qualify row_number() over (partition by id_no, device_no order by device_date, product_date) = 1
)
select d1.*
     , d2.device_no as prev_device_no
     , d2.device_date as prev_device_date
from data d1
asof join data_delta d2
  match_condition(d1.device_date > d2.device_date)
  on (d1.id_no = d2.id_no)
order by d1.product_date
  ;


Thank you very much! This appears to work for my situation.  i will try to 'stress' test it.

try with combo of LAG, CTE and CASE:
WITH DeviceHistory AS (
  SELECT 
    ID_NO,
    DEVICE_NO,
    DEVICE_DATE,
    PRODUCT_NO,
    PRODUCT_DATE,
    LAG(DEVICE_NO) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_NO ORDER BY DEVICE_DATE, PRODUCT_DATE) AS prev_device_no,
    LAG(DEVICE_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_NO ORDER BY DEVICE_DATE, PRODUCT_DATE) AS prev_device_date
  FROM your_table
),
FilteredHistory AS (
  SELECT
    ID_NO,
    DEVICE_NO,
    DEVICE_DATE,
    PRODUCT_NO,
    PRODUCT_DATE,
    CASE 
      WHEN prev_device_no IS NOT NULL AND prev_device_no != DEVICE_NO THEN prev_device_no
      ELSE NULL
    END AS prev_diff_device_no,
    CASE 
      WHEN prev_device_date IS NOT NULL AND prev_device_date != DEVICE_DATE THEN prev_device_date
      ELSE NULL
    END AS prev_diff_device_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_NO, DEVICE_NO ORDER BY DEVICE_DATE, PRODUCT_DATE) AS rn
  FROM DeviceHistory
)
SELECT
  ID_NO,
  DEVICE_NO,
  DEVICE_DATE,
  PRODUCT_NO,
  PRODUCT_DATE,
  prev_diff_device_no AS PREV_DEVICE_NO,
  prev_diff_device_date AS PREV_DEVICE_DATE
FROM FilteredHistory
QUALIFY 
  rn = 1 OR prev_diff_device_no IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ID_NO, DEVICE_DATE, PRODUCT_DATE;


this appears to capture each location and device number, but only the first occurrence.  so it does capture when there was a change in device, but i still need to see each record where a new product was associated. Thanks for the effort.
